# What is the logical system of Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus?

Tags: logic, philosophy

Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus states simply that

> 6 The general form of the truth function is: $[\bar p, \bar\xi, N(\bar \xi)]$. This is the general form of the sentence.

Wikipedia and other sources say

- $\bar p$ stands for an atomic proposition;
- $\bar \xi$ stands for a set of propositions;
- $N(\xi)$ stands for the set of all negations of propositions in $\bar \xi$.

However, this couldn't possibly be correct, because

> 6.03 The general form of the integer is: $[0, \xi, \xi+1]$.

And not a single negation is here. Not only that, $0$ is not an atomic proposition. Not only that, as far as I see, $[0, \xi, \xi+1]$ is not a function of type

$$[0, \xi, \xi+1]: \mathrm{Something} \to \{\top, \bot\}$$

So, what *is* the logical system of Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus?

Comment: Not an answer: consider his clause _4.003 Most of the propositions and questions to be found in philosophical works are not false but nonsensical._ Then read Wittgenstein's Tractatus once more -- isn't it kind of pastime? Next problem, the term **"truth"** is misleading me think, it should be replaced by facts. Example: "Did you commit adultery?" -- "No, I did not." That is the truth of who replies, the questioner's truth may differ.

Comment: It is not a specific formal system, but it is based on *Principia Mathematica*.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192272/roots-of-construing-universal-existential-quantification-as-long-conjunction)

Comment: The $N$ operator is an infinitary [Peirce arrow](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Peirce_arrow).

Answer (score 0):

For the general form of an integer, the notation introduced at **5.2522** is used:

**5.2521** If an operation is applied repeatedly to its own results, I speak of successive applications of it. (*‘O’O’O’a’* is the result of three successive applications of the operation *‘O’ξ’* to *‘a’*.) In a similar sense I speak of successive applications of more than one operation to a number of propositions.

**5.2522** Accordingly I use the sign ‘[*a, x, O’x*]’ for the general term of the series of forms *a, O’a, O’O’a*, . . . .This bracketed expression is a variable: the first term of the bracketed expression is the beginning of the series of forms, the second is the form of a term *x* arbitrarily selected from the series, and the third is the form of the term that immediately follows *x* in the series.

It should be remarked that Wittgenstein's *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus* is not entirely clear of equivocal formulations which have subsequently lead to debates. For example, see the papers, P.T. Geach's “[Wittgenstein's Operator N](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3327740)” and R. J. Fogelin's “[Wittgenstein's Operator N](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3327580)”.